# UItableView Reload Problem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I am using a UiTableView in our application.We have two tabs in controller one is add to shopping list where i add more than one items in our shopping list in database,other one is shopping list which shows items for shopping.

The problem is that when i add items from shopping list tab then items are successfully added in database but when i click on shopping list tab then any items not shown in shopping list.

How i reload data in UiTableView when i click on shopping list tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to reload your tableview....[tableview reloadData]

Answer (score 0):

```
[shoppingTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: i have done this but not working please tell me that where i put this code.